# Re-post HTML form after OpenAM/OpenSSO authentication

Tags: forms, authentication, post, openam, opensso

The default process when authenticating user on OpenAM/OpenSSO works with a 302 http redirection, opening OpenAM/OpenSSO authentication formular. The original URL is stored into "goto" parameter, which allows OpenAM/OpenSSO to redirect the user back on orignal URL after correct authentication.

This works well when using HTTP GET method (i.e. when entering URL), but it is not suitable for POST method. For instance, if the session expires while the user posts a HTML form, the data are lost because HTML form inputs are not present in goto parameter.

Do you know it it is possible to configure J2EE Agent in order it re-posts user HTML form after valid authentication ?

Comment: I suggest you post this on the OpenAM mailing list http://openam.forgerock.org/mail-lists.html
Please post the answer when you get one, I'm verry interested in this one

Answer (score 1):

Both the Java EE and the Web agents support post data preservation, see the [documentation](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/jee-users-guide/index.html#j2ee-agent-post-data-preservation-properties).